# Geocoder - language set to english but still get some results in polish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I'm playing with Geocoder, and try to return english only results.
Language is set to english:

```
2.2.0 :009 > Geocoder.config
 => {:timeout=>3, :lookup=>:google, :ip_lookup=>:freegeoip, :language=>:en, :http_headers=>{}, :use_https=>false, :http_proxy=>nil, :https_proxy=>nil, :api_key=>nil, :cache=>nil, :cache_prefix=>"geocoder:", :always_raise=>[], :units=>:mi, :distances=>:linear}
```

For some queries it works fine and returns english data:
(transl. hint: Warszawa -> Warsaw, Polska -> Poland, Stadion Narodowy -> National Stadium)

```
2.2.0 :010 > Geocoder.search("Warszawa, Polska").first.city
 => "Warsaw"
```

But for others not:

```
2.2.0 :014 > Geocoder.search("Stadion Narodowy, Warszawa, Polska").first.city
 => "Warszawa"
```

The same venue with english name works fine:

```
2.2.0 :015 > Geocoder.search("National Stadium, Warszawa, Polska").first.city
 => "Warsaw"
```

How can I make it return english results all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was due to a [localization update](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html), which makes return responses in the local language. In this case it just seems to be inconsistent information from the query. It would probably best to [file a ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) to get this looked at.

For returning English results, if passing in an English query works `("National Stadium, Warsaw, Poland")`, it sounds like it'd be easiest to just keep the queries in English.